# keep highcharts legend responsive when another div lies over chart

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, sass

I want to display html buttons in the four corners of a HighCharts polar chart's margins. I was able to layer the buttons over the chart div using css. However, doing this results in the chart legend items not responding to mouse clicks.

This is an example of the code for one of the buttons:

```
<div className="pop-chart-button pop-chart-button-top pop-chart-button-left">
  <a role="button" onClick={this.showBrandQuadrantChart}>
    <img src={expandImageUrl} alt="expand" /> BRAND
  </a>
</div>
```

Is there some way to accomplish this that does not make the legend items unresponsive to mouse clicks?

Comment: Could you share all the code (html, js and css) please.

Comment: Shared the scss and js below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by setting a z-index for both chart and button divs and putting the chart div after the div containing the buttons.

Here are the scss styles:

```
.pop-kahn-chart-container {
  position: relative;

  .pop-chart {
    z-index: 99;
  }

  .pop-chart-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    .pop-chart-button {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 0.86rem;
      font-weight: 600;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 9;

      a {
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 2px 8px;
        color: $bp-green;
      }

      a:hover {
        background-color: $bp-gray2;
      }

      img {
        width: 19px;
        height: 19px;
        vertical-align: center;
        position: relative;
        top: -3px;
      }

      @include media-breakpoint-down(lg) {
        font-size: 0.6rem;

        img {
          width: 14.25px;
          height: 14.25px;
          top: -2.25px;
        }
      }
    }

    .pop-chart-button-top {
      top: 10%;
    }

    .pop-chart-button-bottom {
      top: 85%;
    }

    .pop-chart-button-left {
      left: 5%;
    }

    .pop-chart-button-right {
      left: 75%;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code that renders the chart with overlaid buttons:

```
<div className="pop-kahn-chart-container">
  <div className="pop-chart-buttons">
    <div className="pop-chart-button pop-chart-button-top pop-chart-button-left">
      <a role="button" onClick={this.showBrandQuadrantChart}>
        <img src={expandImageUrl} alt="expand" /> BRAND
      </a>
    </div>

    <div className="pop-chart-button pop-chart-button-top pop-chart-button-right">
      <a role="button" onClick={this.showExperienceQuadrantChart}>
        <img src={expandImageUrl} alt="expand" /> EXPERIENCE
      </a>
    </div>

    <div className="pop-chart-button  pop-chart-button-bottom pop-chart-button-left">
      <a role="button" onClick={this.showLowPriceQuadrantChart}>
        <img src={expandImageUrl} alt="expand" /> LOW PRICE
      </a>
    </div>

    <div className="pop-chart-button pop-chart-button-bottom pop-chart-button-right">
      <a role="button" onClick={this.showFrictionlessQuadrantChart}>
        <img src={expandImageUrl} alt="expand" /> FRICTIONLESS
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="pop-chart">
    <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This example demonstrated both z-indices needed to be set: https://codepen.io/hobart9579/pen/ryoopN

Answer (score 0):

Just by guessing without seeing your CSS code, the buttons z-index is underneath the chart. Setting the buttons to a higher z-index will probably fix the issue.

Comment: Setting the z-index did turn out to be necessary. However, the chart div's z-index needs to be higher than the button div's z-indices.